70's sci-fi movie or series with a young Native American on a quest to find strange looking medallions
Maybe this is a 70's movie or series. Saw it on TV when I was a kid (around 1978).
Young Native American on a quest to find strange looking medallions.
The medallions are square and shiny and at least one is found on the neck of a giant skeleton. The skeleton may be extraterrestrial. The young Native American has a wise grandfather. He is heard saying that death is always on your left... sometimes close and sometimes far away.

Live action or animated?

Search for the Gods (1975). There is a single medallion broken into multiple parts scattered across the country (globe?) and an elderly native American spends his time trying to locate them. The elderly man utters gibberish about death being behind them to his cellmate, who is requested to give a piece of the medallion to his grand daughter. We eventually find out the medallion is of extraterrestrial origin. At the end of the movie they find a piece around the neck of a corpse located in a tomb. It stars a very young Kurt Russell.
Skeleton/medallions scene:




Skeleton/medallions scene: https://youtu.be/3hKDR_TeXqQ?t=5270

@spike72  Kurt Russel was not "very young" in 1975.   He had already been acting for more than a decade.

Anyone under 40 is young to me!
